# Google MapActivity not displaying map

Tags: android, google-maps, keytool

I am trying to get google maps working. It is not displaying the map. I get the following error in LogCat

```
Couldn't get connection factory client
```

I have been through all the duplicate posts, and made the following changes

- Ensured that uses-permission and uses-library are inside  tag
- used debug.keystore instead of custom
- signed up with google maps using my private key, and updated my MapView with the maps key in the xml (for this public post, I have changed it)
- Exported my app, and used debug.keystore to build it

I am running it on emulator. Maps on emulator works.

Android Manifest

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
    <activity
        android:name=".MyActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".GetLocation" android:label="@string/app_name"/>
</application>
```

location.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.google.android.maps.MapView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:apiKey="0psLgKtDQLB35-XJXUrjR4bKHIBDRuHu-O-xVhg"
    android:id="@+id/location"
/>

sudo keytool -list -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android -keystore     debug.keystore
```

returns

```
androiddebugkey, 20 Mar, 2012, PrivateKeyEntry, 
Certificate fingerprint (MD5): 20:D3:54:D9:F8:70:17:A4:BA:21:5C:98:88:27:45:E0
```

Fixed
I put uses-permission outside of Application tag
And uses-library inside of Application tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`uses-permission` outside the `<application>` Tag. and

> Couldn't get connection factory client

And its map-api key problem .And you should create Fresh Map-api key .

Comment: I still get the "Couldn't get connection factory client" error. But it works.

Comment: @Siddharth are you sure <uses permission> is outside <application> Tag  in manifest file

Comment: Yes, I just put it in there, refreshed, exported using my debug.keystore and the map displayed. The error still shows, feels silly.

Comment: @Siddharth i have same issue its work after sometimes and this error doesnt make any problem and try after sometime it may be due to google map

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11179/discussion-between-siddharth-and-samir-mangroliya)

Answer (score 1):

I believe you might have got the solution for this question but for anyone else looking for the help for same question here's the ans

try to put

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>    
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

outside your application tag

just leave
`<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />` inside the tag

add metadata inside the application tag as

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
android:value="your API key"/>
```

and it will definitely work fine